# cursor: pointer on a div does not work

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Drives me nuts. Bars do not inherit cursor from `.menu.container`

```css
.menu.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu.container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Rename ```menu.container``` to ```menu-container``` and your problem should be solved, the rule is currently parsed as ```.container``` in a ```.menu```.

Comment: Actually, it's parsed as a `.container` _and_ a `.menu`

Comment: Oh, was it and? Always confuse those relation rules.. guess ```>``` was in then.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're defining a class with a period within its name `menu.container`

The css that you've written is interpreted as `class = 'menu container'`

Answer (score 1):

```css
.menu_container {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px;
    transition: 0.4s;  
   }
```

```html
<div class="menu_container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dots in class names must be escaped by `\` in CSS - see demo below:

```css
.menu\.container {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px;
    transition: 0.4s;  
   }
```

```html
<div class="menu.container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't know that was possible... Nice!

Answer (score 0):

**If menu and container are two classes**

```css
.menu {
    display:inline-block;
    cursor: pointer !important;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 35px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px;
    transition: 0.4s;  
   }
```

```html
<div class="menu container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```